# jQuery Cycle Plugin - Image stretching to width of browser in IE 9 on Windows 7 pro

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, cycle

I've set the width and height of all the containing divs and the images themselves but it still shows up stretched to full width of the browser after it transitions to the 2nd image.

http://goo.gl/rUZy7 (used a short url so this doesn't show up in the SE's for the main url)

I'm at a loss here and have run out of options, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bumped into this issue recently.

I updated the plugin's file to the most recent version and it fixed the issue for me.  In my experience the plugin I was using was not supported by IE9.

Here's the link to the updated file:

http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.lite.js